# How to use Drag & Drop dnd:removeFile event?

Tags: media, files

I'm using Drag & Drop module to let users upload an image in their profile (I'm using a custom profile tpl).

In that custom profile, I'm using in-place editable fields with AngularJS, so there isn't any form submit button (each field has it's own one).

That's why I need to save the uploaded image automatically **in the user account**, which I've achieved by using the "dnd:send:complete" javascript event.

Now I need to use "dnd:removeFile" event to remove image automatically **from user account** when the "Remove" button is clicked, but I can't get it to work.

I apply "dnd:send:complete" event to the Drag & Drop upload element itself, but... to which element do I have to apply "dnd:removeFile" (since when default image is shown, system is using the default managed_file system to remove the image).

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding upload element and I can hardly find any documentation about it.

P.D. Please, note that the problem is not removing the image itself, but removing it's relationship with the user account.